# ConEmu keep terminal open after run command using default style

Tags: windows, cmd, conemu

I want to create a shortcut to run a command and then let the terminal open. Example in cmd.exe:

- `cmd.exe /k ping 8.8.8.8`

Also would like for it to just open 1 tab

Also I would like to have the colors from default start:

[image: pic1]

- `ConEmu64.exe`
- `ConEmu64.exe -run {Shells::cmd}`

Currently I have:

[image: pic2]

- `ConEmu64.exe -run cmd.exe /k "ping 8.8.8.8"`

But I miss the colors and default prompt. Any way I can have both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
ConEmu64.exe -run {Shells::cmd} & ping 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I don't think I would have found it, I have spent a lot of time in the documentation. Maybe a simple example like this will help. Thanks awesome app.